# Insert and Remove Element in Deque using threads in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, multithreading, thread-safety, queue

The following code works fine for inserting and removing an element from a deque using two threads.

I would appreciate any help on how to make it better, especially in terms of thread safety.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <deque>

#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

#define SLEEP_TIME 1

std::deque <int> q;
std::mutex _mu;
std::condition_variable cond;

void function1()
{
    int count = 10;

    while (count > 0)
    {

        std::unique_lock <std::mutex> locker(_mu);
        q.push_front(count);
        locker.unlock();
        cond.notify_one();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(SLEEP_TIME));

        count--;
    }

    return;
}

void function2()
{
    int data = 0;

    while (data != 1)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(_mu);
        cond.wait(locker);

        data = q.back();
        q.pop_back();
        locker.unlock(),

        std::cout << "T2 gets " << data << " from T1" << std::endl;
    }

    return;

}

int main() {

    std::thread t2(function1);
    std::thread t1(function2);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    std::cout << "Thread Function Executed Successfully" << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Isolate platform-specific code

If you must have `stdafx.h`, consider wrapping it so that the code is portable:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif
```

In this code, with a single file, the use of `stdafx.h` does not gain anything on any platform, including Windows.

### Don't use leading underscores in names

Anything with a leading underscore is a *reserved name* in C++ (and in C).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier) for details.

### Be careful with conditional variables

Right now, `t2` waits for a conditional variable and `t1` sets it.  If `t1` never pushes anything to the deque, `t2` would wait forever and never terminate.  Similarly, if `t1` is launched before `t2`, it could execute the `cond.notify_one()` before any threads are waiting for that variable, so `t1` would push 10 and notify, but no thread would "hear" the notification with the effect that `t2` would only be notified after `t1` pushes 9.  The effect is that the code would *almost* work but never terminate.  To allow the launching of threads in either order, I'd recommend that `t2` should keep `pop`ping until the deque is empty.  This is a typical pattern in multithreaded code.

### Remember that `main` is a thread, too

I realize that this code is probably written for practice using threads and locks and such, but it's important to remember that `main` is also a thread, so this program actually uses three threads and not two.  Because the `main` function isn't really doing anything useful while the threads are running, an alternative approach would be to launch only `t1` as a thread and then simply invoke `function2` directly from `main`, thereby using only two threads instead of three and getting the same work accomplished.

### Remember that `std::cout` is a shared resource

It's not an issue in this code because only one thread at a time prints to `std::cout`, but as you create more complex code, it's important to remember that `std::cout` is a shared resource, too,  For that reason, you'll want to have a `mutex` for access to it as well if you want to avoid possible interleaving of output.

Comment: Using `stdafx.h` as a "master" header would be perfectly legal on all platforms. And while you're right that it doesn't gain anything for a single file out of context, precompiled headers can offer a huge improvement in build times for large projects. If you make it conditional when building on Windows, you aren't doing yourself any favors, because now you have two different lists of includes to manage, depending on which environment you're building in.

Comment: Or, one could address all of those objections by simply omitting the line.

Comment: No, you couldn't, because then you cannot gain the benefits of precompiled headers with Microsoft's compiler.

Answer (score 0):

The code in function2 is logically incorrect. Remember that condition_variables have spurious wakeups. You must test an actual condition, otherwise you may end up taking a reference to the back of an empty queue:

```
while (data != 1)
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> locker(_mu);

    // there must be a predicate
    while(not q.empty())
    {
        cond.wait(locker);
    }

    data = q.back();
    q.pop_back();
    locker.unlock(),

    std::cout << "T2 gets " << data << " from T1" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made changes to the second function as I read further. Also, there is another problem,  that the second thread, T2 will keep waiting for a notification from T1. I also made changes for that as well. Thank you for the heads up :)